Custom quantity input step based on WooCommerce product category
I have been trying to get decimal quantities to work in WooCommerce, and I am at a loss for why it's not working.
My plugin code (see below) successfully allows the inputs to be decimals in 0.5 increments as expected for all products in the "Fabric" category. So far, so good. It also allows quantity updates in the cart to be done as 0.5 increments.
However, when I add a product with a fractional quantity to the cart or when I click Update in the cart after changing the quantity to a fractional number, the amount added is an integer anyway. I know this because adding 2.5, for example, still results in a total of 2 * price in the cart (as well as displaying only 2 items in the cart). (Also, when we click "Add to Cart" with the 2.5 quantity, the notice says "Added 2 items to cart.")
So somewhere, I am missing some setting or code that actually takes the fractional quantity input being selected without truncating it. Has anyone else had this problem? Everything I can find online is that the code below should work.
Thanks for any help you can provide.
Here is my code, largely based on other solutions on this site:
(I'm using Wordpress 6.5.2)
// Removes the WooCommerce filter, that is validating the quantity to be an int
remove_filter('woocommerce_stock_amount', 'intval');

// Add a filter, that validates the quantity to be a float
add_filter('woocommerce_stock_amount', 'floatval');

// Add min value to the quantity field (default = 1)
add_filter('woocommerce_quantity_input_min', 'min_decimal');
function min_decimal($val) {
    return 1;
}

// Add step value to the quantity field (default = 1)
add_filter('woocommerce_quantity_input_step', 'step_decimal', 10, 2);
function step_decimal($val, $product) {

    $product_id = $product->get_id();
    
    if (has_term('Fabric','product_cat', $product_id)) {
        return 0.5;
    }
    
    return 1.0;
}


Try the following revised and simplified code version instead:
remove_filter('woocommerce_stock_amount', 'intval');
add_filter('woocommerce_stock_amount', 'floatval');

add_filter( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_args', 'filter_quantity_input_args', 10, 2 );
function filter_quantity_input_args( $args, $product ){
    $product_id = $product->get_parent_id() > 0 ? $product->get_parent_id() : $product->get_id();
    
    if ( has_term('Fabric', 'product_cat', $product_id) ) {
        $args['min_value'] = 1;
        $args['step'] = 0.5;
    }
    return $args;
}

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). Tested and works.

I tried with the modified code provided (thank you!), and I get the same truncating behavior. I also deactivated all plugins that have any features related to product quantities, and nothing changed. A while back (several versions ago), I had this working using the code I originally posted, so I am wondering if it's a WordPress version issue. I am currently adding a logger to my code to dump data to see if this is a truncation issue that is propagating to the cart page or if the decimal quantities are not being picked up at all when added in the first place.

Update: I used the 'woocommerce_add_to_cart' hook to write the quantity parameter to the WC log, and the quantity sent to the handler function has been truncated to an integer anyway. The code allows the customer to select a fractional quantity, but clicking Add To Cart truncates it right away. I don't see anyone else having this behavior, so I am at a loss at the moment.

For me it works just fine with latest WooCommerce and WordPress versions (note that I tested that with Classic Cart and checkout (Legacy shortcode Pages)…

Something else must be interfering. This is the only code in my plugin, but I will try putting it directly into the functions.php file instead. Weirdly, the quantity selection allows for the decimal stepping just fine. But the confirmation buttons (Add to Cart or Update) end up resulting in truncated integers anyway, which is a behavior I can't seem to find anyone else experiencing. Will post updates as I try various changes. Thanks for sticking with me!

More updates, no solutions: Manually calling the url with add-to-cart and a fractional quantity (i.e. not clicking the button) results in the same truncated behavior. Interestingly, the added_to_cart return URL shows the right quantity in the url, BUT I have confirmed the truncated integer quantity is what is being sent to both the "woocommerce_add_to_cart" and "wc_add_to_cart_message_html" hooks. Lastly, I changed themes to see if my theme was interfering, but no luck. Same behavior with both themes. I also queried the database directly to see the cart, and it also showed truncated numbers.

More updates, partial solution: I found that the code works if put into the functions.php file of the theme (using a child theme). So any thoughts on why my plugin with the same code is behaving differently from the theme's functions.php file? Is there a priority issue I don't understand, or some setting in the theme file I need to make sure I modify properly? The display of what got added and remaining inventory are rounded still, but I think that's just an html issue I can figure out separately. Should I create a new question for this?

Will do. I will note my original code works also, for anyone reading this.

Closing the loop: The original code was correct, though not as streamlined as the first suggested solution. Moving the code from a plugin functions.php to the child theme functions.php did the trick. Not sure why, but if it helps someone else, that was the ultimate solution to the problem I was having.
